# Try to send emails but i can't..... i got this fatal error

Tags: php

I'm learning sendemail and in my display model I got the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files(x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\test\email.phpon line 11

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST ['submit'] ) ) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $comments = $_POST['comment'];
        $to ="rzeb14@yahoo.com";
        $headers ="From: $name<$email>";
          $msg = "name: $name \n\n  email: $email \n\n subject $subject \n\n comment $comments  ";
         if(mail($to, $subject, $msg , $headers))
         {
            echo "sendd msg";
         }
         else
         {
            echo "try again plz";
         }
    }

?>



<html>
<head><title>ghg</title></head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <p>name:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="" />  </p>

        <p>email:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="" />  </p>

        <p>sub:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="" />  </p>

        <p>comment:<br/>
        <textarea name="comment" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> </p>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="sendemail" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Increase your execution time from within `php.ini` file

Comment: Please, format your code!

Comment: @Uchiha: Sorry, but more than 30 seconds for an email being sent? Okay, with a slow network connection. But then a synchronous method is wrong here.

Comment: Have you configured the server to send mail?

Comment: problem is seems email configuration not done on your server.thanks.

Comment: Why not use SMTP ? It's far better than `mail` function !

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen `mail` uses SMTP protocol. Are you thinking of [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I thought both have bit differences.. Isn't it ?

Comment: No. It's like saying "Use HTTP, it's far better than Google Chrome browser". `mail` uses SMTP protocol to send email.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Ah, Got it mate :) Thanks Will study on it :)

Comment: @uchiha Yes i increase execution time from within php.ini file.but got same error

Comment: @ Richard Reiber how i can format my code  actually  i am beginner in PHP 4